# How to get cassandra to filter correctly?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am a newbie in cassandra and currently trying out the temperature example from datastax.
In the example, I create a table with following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.temperature (
    weatherstation_id text,
    event_time timestamp,
    temperature text,
    PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id, event_time)
) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
   AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
   AND comment = ''
   AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 }
   AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
   AND default_time_to_live = 0
   AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE'
   AND min_index_interval = 128
   AND max_index_interval = 2048
   AND crc_check_chance = 1.0;
```

containing the following data:

```
cqlsh> use mykeyspace;
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from temperature where weatherstation_id='1234ABCD'
              ... ;

 weatherstation_id | event_time               | temperature
-------------------+--------------------------+-------------
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 06:01:00+0000 |         72F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 06:02:00+0000 |         73F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 06:03:00+0000 |         73F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 06:04:00+0000 |         74F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 06:05:00+0000 |         72F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 07:01:00+0000 |         72F
```

However, the filtering does not work and still return the full set when I run the following cql:

```
select * from temperature where weatherstation_id='1234ABCD' and event_time > '2013-04-03 06:05:00';
```

Do I understand the condition wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you understand the condition correctly.  But when working with timestamps, Cassandra assumes that you are working in your local GMT offset.  When I run your last query, I don't get any rows returned at all.  But when I specify a GMT offset of `+0000`, I get a single row.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM temperature 
    WHERE weatherstation_id='1234ABCD' AND event_time > '2013-04-03 06:05:00+0000';

 weatherstation_id | event_time               | temperature
-------------------+--------------------------+-------------
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 07:01:00+0000 |         72F

(1 rows)
```

Alter your `eventime >` section to include the GMT offset of +0000 as I have, and you should see the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Aaron :) I finally got it to work after adding the timezone offset +xxxx. One strange thing is that I have already changed local timezone to GMT, yet I still need to append +0000 to timestamp.